# My character is moving automatically to the opposite side and falling out (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm a beginner in using Unity and C#, i'm trying to make a 2d game and i followed 2 tutorials on youtube, but they gave the same result. my character is moving to the left side automatically without pressing any key and falling out. This is my code that i used for the movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Walk : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementSpeed = 1 ;

    public void Start () 
    {

    }
    private void Update () 
    {        
        {
            var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  I would check your keybinds (Edit>Project Settings>InputManager>Axes>Horizontal)

Look for:

- Gravity: how fast the RAW value resets to zero (ignored by joystick inputs)
- Dead: Deadspace either side of zero. (ie, if (-Dead < Raw < Dead) return zero)
- Sensitivity: how fast the RAW value travels to limit [-1, 1] when pressing keys (ignored by joystick axes)

By default:

- Gravity should be 3
- Dead should be 0.001
- Sensitivity should be 3
- Type should be "Key or Mouse Button" unless you're expecting controller/joystick (or mouse) motion as input.

Answer (score -2):

As you are new you have created a very normal mistake that you have written
transform.position += new Vector3(movement,0,0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
In update function (Update function do the work every frame)
To correct it write

if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
transform.position += new Vector3(movement,0,0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
}

Also here I have written Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) which means left click of mouse
Just like that
Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)(which means right click of mouse)
If you want to move with and certain key visit manual
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html

Comment: ```GetAxis``` ***IS CORRECT*** for retrieving axis values from (classic) Input system.